# C++ supporting user entered array size on stack memory

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, c++17, c++14

I was surprised to see that below code works in C++.

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int arr[n];
```

which is violating most of the information available on internet in this context, that, array size should be compile time known.
Is the above feature/behavior is universally rolled out and accepted, or it is just compiler dependent or C++ language version dependent?

Comment: it's VLA (variable-length array), a commonly-supported extension, since it is a part of the C standard, but not C++.

Comment: It is compiler dependent, but pretty common. GCC and Clang for example accept to create VLA by default, but not in their -pedantic mode.

Comment: fwiw, there was a proposal to have something similar to VLAs in C++ (i think it was C++14), but it wasn't accepted eventually